# How to redirect WAN https traffic to (local) http socket?

Tags: nginx

i tried to redirect https://example.com/service to http://1.2.3.4:5678/cgi-bin/luci

I have a couple of subdirs running but unfortunately missing something here.

If i do:

```
    location /service/ {
            proxy_pass http://1.2.3.4:5678/cgi-bin/luci/;
    }
```

the desired page shows up for a couple of ms. Then it dissapears and the address changes from /service/ to /cgi-bin/luci instead of /service/cgi-bin/luci/

Could anybody tell me what iam doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it possible that the one doing the redirect is your application? and not nginx

Comment: hmm. Dunno. Is there any chance to figure out without insight to the app itself?